# How to handle complex search in a Flutter Firebase project?

Tags: flutter, firebase, elasticsearch, google-cloud-firestore

The app offers the users the ability to find vehicles from filters (search vectors): they could build a filter that say: find all suv or sedan cars from vw or renault brands built from year 2017 and up where power is between 4 and 6 CV inclusive.

The app build such a filter as a json like so:

```
{
  type: ["suv", "sedan"],
  brand: ["vw", "renault"],
  date: {"min": "2017-01-01"},
  cv: {"min": 4, "max": 6}
}
```

Of course, more items could be add to the filter.

The cars are stored in Firestone, document looks like so:

```
{
  type: "suv",
  brand: "renault",
  model: "clio 5",
  date: "2020-06-01",
  cv: 5,
}
```

Due to Firestone limitations (could not add more than one `whereIn` per request, I am looking for an alternative.

I wonder if elastic search could be a nice fit with the stack I use and the requirement I have or if other choices would be more suited.

What do you think?

Update: here is the way I build the Firestore request from the json:

```dart
  /// Returns the classified query which handles clearedForSale
  static Query<Map<String, dynamic>> getQuery(
      {bool includeNotClearedForSale = false}) {
    late final Query<Map<String, dynamic>> snapshot;

    if (includeNotClearedForSale) {
      snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName);
    } else {
      snapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(collectionName)
          .where("clearedForSale", isEqualTo: true);
    }

    return snapshot;
  }

  /// Builds the request from the given filter
  static Query<ClassifiedAd> getQueryFromFilter(Map<String, dynamic> filter) {
    var q = getQuery();

    for (final field in filter.keys) {

      final f = filter[field];

      // The field must match at least one of the values

      if (f is Set) {
        final list = f.toList();
        debugPrint("getQueryFromFilter: add constraint: $field whereIn $list");

        if (list.length == 1) {
          q = q.where(field, isEqualTo: list.first);
        } else {
          q = q.where(field, whereIn: list);
        }
      }

      // The field must fall wihin the range

      else if (f is Map) {
        if (f["min"] != null && f["max"] != null) {
          if (f["min"] > f["max"]) {
            final min = f["min"];
            f["min"] = f["max"];
            f["max"] = min;
          }
        }

        if (f["min"] != null) {
          q = q.where(field, isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: f["min"]);
        }
        if (f["max"] != null) {
          q = q.where(field, isLessThanOrEqualTo: f["max"]);
        }
      }

      // The field must be eqal to the value?

      else {
        q = q.where(field, isEqualTo: f);
      }
    }

    return q
        //.orderBy('creationDate', descending: true)
        .withConverter<ClassifiedAd>(
      fromFirestore: adFromFireStore,
      toFirestore: (ad, doc) => ad.toMap(),
    );
  }
```

[UPDATE]

Let me tell the issue with simple sentences to make it clearer.

A filter is a series of `AND` conditions of various types:

- `where in`: that is for example, where `brand` is any of the following value ["bmv", "ford", "gm",etc.]`;
- `range`: that is for example, where `horsePower` is greater than or equal to `100` and lower than or equal to `600`;
- `equality`: that is fo example `color` equals to `green`.

I face two limitations:

1. only one `whereIn`per query;
2. no more than 10 values in a `whereIn`.

I could work around the latter by using `or`. But the first one has none to my knowledge.

As a consequence, I break the queries into many queries (one per `whereIn`). I run all them waiting with an `await Future.wait(series);`.

Then I reduce the result by only selecting documents that have their `id` returned by all queries.

Not sure it is a good solution.

My alternative would be to use `Elastic search`to perform the searches.

Comment: What is the DB structure, which query did you try, was there any error, are you using elastic Search extension or using it's npm package? Also have a look at this [Link](https://extensions.dev/extensions/algolia/firestore-algolia-search).

Comment: Thanks for your interest, but please read the question. For your convenience I added the dart code that create the query from the json I gave in the question

Comment: Have you seen [OR](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#or_queries) queries?

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks for the advice but what I need is a series of AND that says for example: brand in ["vmv", "ford", "gm",…] and model in ["308", …] AND etc. How the OR might help me? I could use it to replace each whereIn to extends to more than 10 values, but that's it. Maybe I am wrong. I updated my question to make it clearer and I'd love your advise about that.